# Why does Java compile this equation: 78 / 10 * 10 + 10 - 78 equal to 2?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I've been trying to understand java operator precedence but I can't wrap my head around this equation someone has given to me. By adding parentheses myself I get (((78 / 10) * 10) + 10) - 78 but this shouldn't equate to 2. Can someone explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: Because it is, int division will truncate. The parenthesis are unnecessary. If you want the mathematically correct answer use `float` or `double`: `78.0 / 10 * 10 + 10 - 78`, the `.0` in the first term will ensure it's done using `double` (or `float`?, check documentation) instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
78 / 10 = 7
7 * 10 = 70
70 + 10 = 80
80 - 78 = 2
```

remember an int /int will be an int

a float / int will be a float so you could do the following:

```
(float)78 / 10 * 10 + 10 - 78 or 78.0 / 10 * 10 + 10 - 78
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I completely forgot it stay an int, thanks so much.

Comment: no problem, accept answer if you're clear on what's going on

Comment: Add to the answer how to go around this by casting (implicit or explicit).

Answer (score 0):

It's because in integer math 78 / 10 is 7, not 7.8

Then:

```
 7 * 10 = 70
   + 10 = 80
   - 78 =  2
```